# Character in math mode replacement

Tags: search, replace

I would like to replace instances of a single character variable, say `x`, throughout all my equations in a latex file, say the replacement is `\x`.

The equations are denoted by one of the following:

```
\begin{equation} \end{equation}
\[ \]
$ $
```

I could use `:%s,x,\\x,gc` but then I would have to confirm all instances of x that are not in math mode.

Is there any way to bound the range to be inside math modes only?

Comment: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4050/how-to-search-for-pattern-in-certain-syntax-regions might of use  (it's just search, but it should be possible to adapt the solutions for replace as well)

Comment: If you are on a posix system I'd suggest to use an external filter like `1GVG!sed '/begin{equation}/,/end{equation}/s/x/\\x/g'`. I believe it's okay to different tools for different purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:g/\\begin{equation}/,/\\end{equation}/s/x/\\x/g`

This will look for `x` between `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` 
and will substitute all instances of `x` with `\x`.

To look for the pattern `x` inside `\[ \]` and `$ $`, replace the matching pattern and do a search replace again. If you want all the search instances in one line, use `|` to separate two search expressions.